# How to create a hyperlink cell in excel using telerik XlsxFormatProvider

Tags: telerik

According to this link https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/libraries/radspreadprocessing/formats-and-conversion/import-and-export-to-excel-file-formats/xlsx/features you can create a cell in excel as a hyperlink, but I cannot find any documentation as to how to actually do it.

Can anyone point me in the direction to the documentation or supply an example

Answer (score 0):

Found link https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/libraries/radspreadprocessing/features/hyperlink

But I had to change slightly to spreadsheetHyperlink.HyperlinkInfo.Address